# Magento Commerce - How to link to a search result without a trailing "/"

Tags: magento, search, dynamic-linking

Hello I have a site with a bunch of brand name logos on the homepage. I want to link each to a list of all the products that fall under that brand. I achieving this by using this:  it links to the search results for that brand name but it adds a trailing “/” and that doesn't seem to effect all of the search results but some of them return no search results because of the “/”. Any ideas on how to solve this or even a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how many brands you have in the homepage. I'd take this:

http://www.dnawebagency.com/displaying-new-products-in-magento-with-pagination (Route 2)

modifying the filter for each brand code and removing the dates.